# Want to clean those hard-to-reach stubborn files (Windows 10 and Google Drive)

Tags: windows-10, google-drive, cleaning

OK well the start of this project was that I wanted to donate or give away some my old computers. One of them is a Sony integrated VPCJ1 PC nearly ten years old, now running Windows 10, which is still running well although it is getting a bit slow. I have backed up all the user data on it and now want to make sure that I've removed all personal files as far as possible. I know there were at least three options open to me:

(a) Use something like DBAN to wipe the hard drive completely

(b) Reset Windows and reload the system

(c) Remove each user, just leaving a single 'Admin' account.

I chose option (c) because I wanted to pass the computer on as a going concern with a working copy of Windows and Microsoft Office.

So far so good.

After removing each user in turn, I found to my dismay that the hard drive (as reported by Explorer) was still nearly full with about 300GB unaccounted for. I then took the following steps:

(1) Ran chkdsk /f to see if the missing space was somehow in unallocated clusters. It made no difference.

(2) Took advice from several web posts to download WinDirStat. This was more successful, and I could see that the directory for my username and all its files (Tom) still existed (though invisible to explorer and Dir). Although I couldn't delete the entire directory, I was able to gradually step through and delete most of the files.

(3) A few folders remained, so I took advice from [here](https://www.tenforums.com/user-accounts-family-safety/113049-deleted-user-but-folder-remains-its-locked-how-delete.html) to delete the profile key for Tom from the registry. This helped - I was then able to see the folders in explorer and delete a few more of them.

(4) Even running Explore as administrator there were a couple of folders I couldn't delete. To be honest the accompanying files (which are in fact just stubs as far as I can see) are pretty much in the public domain and Wedding is an empty folder but this has become something of a mission and I'm wondering if anyone can suggest how I delete the remainder (this computer is not currently online to Google Drive and I don't particularly want to delete the actual files from Google Drive, just the links to them).

[image]

(5) Using force delete running CMD prompt as administrator enabled me to remove the individual files on Google Drive, leaving the empty Wedding folder and .tmp.drivedownload. I noticed that Attrib revealed the following:

[image]

Comment: BTW I'm wondering after asking this question whether it was the presence of the Google Drive files that stopped the deletion of the files belonging to user Tom in the first place? Difficult to prove, but might be a follow-up question.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get rid of those last few stubborn files and folders using this technique.
(The user account was deleted from computer and domain long ago, but the user folder didn't empty due to Google Drive folder)

1. Right click the folder that isn't allowed to delete or access. Select Properties, Security, Advanced.
2. Change owner to your current user (I did mine as COMPUTERNAME\admin)
3. Check the box "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects".
4. Click Ok.
5. Enter Advanced again
6. In Permissions tab, make sure the COMPUTERNAME\admin user has full access, otherwise add it.
7. Check the little box at the bottom to "Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object".
8. Click Ok again.
9. Close properties dialogue
10. Delete the folder
11. Repeat with next folder.

It worked for me to delete everything manually, even the stubborn .tmp.drivedownload, desktop.ini files and all other that had been synced.
Also seemed to work for all subfolders on synced folders, no matter on amount of subfolders. So only the top of each synced folder had to be treated like this.
It din't however work directly on the "Google Drive" folder, until it was totally empty, I don't know why.